# Pesquisa em Select por amostragem de períodos

Tags: php, html5

Estou criando uma aplicação, e no caso essa aplicação terá vários filtros para o usuário.

Um deste filtro é o famoso pesquisa por data. No caso, o usuário faz a a pesquisa entre as duas datas desejadas e escolhe 3 tipos de amostragem desses dados, ou eles irão aparecer Diários, ou semanal ou mensal. No caso, a amostragem diária eu consegui fazer, porém travei na mensal. No caso, fiz um contador em *strtotime* para a amostragem diária. Fui usar a mesma técnica para a semanal porém se alguém escolher um período diferente do múltiplo de 7, ele não mostra o restante. Tentei fazer um esquema de resto, porém não funcionou, sobrando só pegando a amostragem dos períodos exatos. E no caso precisaria que seja feito a amostragem com o período quebrado. Ex: Se o usuário escolher um período de 10 dias com a amostragem semanal, a primeira consulta será de 7 dias e a segunda será de 3 dias.

Segue abaixo o trecho do código de Diário e semanal.

```
 //Período Diário
                if($periodo == "Diaria") { 
                    $periodo1 = $data_ini_;
                    $periodo2 = $data_fim_;




                        while($periodo1 <= $periodo2) { 


                            //echo "<BR>DENTRO DO LOOP<BR>";
                            //echo $periodo1."<BR>";
                            //$periodoDiario = $periodo1; 
                            $saidaPeriodo = "Dia $periodo1";

                            $where = "BETWEEN '$periodo1' AND 
'$periodo1 23:59:59')";
                            //echo $where."<BR>";

                            $consulta = "SELECT GITEC, SUM (DATEDIFF 
 (second,INICIO,DT_FECHAMENTO_OCORRENCIA)) as Soma_tempo, AVG 
 (DATEDIFF (second,INICIO,DT_FECHAMENTO_OCORRENCIA)) Media_tempo
                            FROM [readb004].[dbo].
 [reavw002_ocorrencias_historicos_cgr] 
                            WHERE ([INICIO]  $where AND $where1 
  $where2 $where3 $where4 AND ([USUARIO_REGISTRO] NOT IN 
  ('SISTEMA','Remedy ...','CETEC72' )) AND ([QUEDA_MASSIVA] = 0)
                            GROUP BY  GITEC  
                            order by  GITEC DESC";


                            //AND $where1 $where2 $where3

                            //echo $consulta."<BR>";


                            $periodo1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 
   day",strtotime($periodo1))); 








                //echo $consulta; 







                //BETWEEN '$data_ini_' AND '$data_fim_

                    //Formata o resultado 

                    $result = $sqlq->execute($consulta); 
                        while(!$result->EOF) { 
                            $gitec = $result->Fields['GITEC']->Value; 
                            $soma_tempo = $result-
 >Fields['Soma_tempo']->Value; 
                            $media_tempo = $result-
 >Fields['Media_tempo']->Value; 


                            $horas_gitec = floor($soma_tempo/ 3600); 
                            $minutos_gitec = floor(($soma_tempo - 
   ($horas_gitec * 3600)) / 60);    
                            $segundos_gitec = floor($soma_tempo%60); 
                            $hora_result = 
   $horas_gitec.':'.$minutos_gitec.':'.$segundos_gitec;
                            $htotal_msg = 
  date("H:i:s",strtotime($hora_result));    

                            $horas_gitec2 = floor($media_tempo / 
  3600);
                            $minutos_gitec2 = floor(($media_tempo - 
  ($horas_gitec2 * 3600)) / 60);        
                            $segundos_gitec2 = floor($media_tempo%60); 
                            $hora_res = 
 $horas_gitec2.':'.$minutos_gitec2. ":".$segundos_gitec2;
                            $hora_msg = 
    date("H:i:s",strtotime($hora_res)); 



                            $consultaData = "SELECT [gitec],
  [data_migracao] FROM [Ocorrencias].[dbo].[Tb_data_migracao] WHERE 
  [gitec] ='$gitec'"; 
                            //Executa a consulta    
                            $resGitec = $sql->execute($consultaData); 
                                $gitNova = $resGitec->Fields['gitec']-
  >Value; 
                                $data_migracao = $resGitec-
     >Fields['data_migracao']->Value; 

                                $dataTeste = $data_migracao; 

                                //echo $dataTeste."<BR>"; 





                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$gitec</td>"; 

                            if($dataTeste > $periodo1) {        

                        echo "<td>$saidaPeriodo</td>
                              <!--<td>$htotal_msg</td>-->
                              <td>$hora_msg</td>
                              <!--<td>-</td>-->
                              <td>-</td>
                              <td>-</td>
                            </tr>
                        "; } else { 

                            echo "<td>$saidaPeriodo</td>
                              <!--<td></td>-->
                              <td>-</td>
                              <!--<td>$htotal_msg</td>-->
                              <td>$hora_msg</td>
                              <td>-</td>"; 
                        }   



                    $result ->MoveNext(); } 
                    } } else if ($periodo = "Semanal") { 

                            $periodo1 = $data_ini_;
                            $periodo2 = $data_fim_;

                            echo $periodo1."<BR>"; 
                            echo $periodo2."<BR>"; 

                            echo "<BR>";        

                                while($periodo1 <= $periodo2) { 


                                    echo "<BR>DENTRO DO LOOP<BR>";
                                    echo $periodo1."<BR>";
                                    $saidaPeriodo = ""; 

                                    $periodo1 = date("Y-m-d", 
              strtotime("+7 day",strtotime($periodo1)));
```

No caso, o que eu poderia fazer para que está amostragem Semanal de certo?